# create new object from object of arrays

Tags: javascript

I have the following object in Javascript:

```
let directions = {
  "vertical": [
    "down",
    "up",
  ],
  "horizontal": [
    "left",
    "right",
  ]
}
```

and need to find a way to create another object from it that looks like this:

```
left plainDirections = {
  "left",
  "right",
  "down",
  "up"
}
```

I have tried this:

```
function getDirectionValues() {
  let a = {};
  Object.values(config.directions).forEach(element => {
    a = {...a , element};
  });
  return a;
}
```

but it does not give the desired result.  When it's called then logged to the console the output is:

```
Object {
  "directionValues": Object {
    "element": Array [
      "down",
      "up",
    ],
  },
}
```

Comment: The syntax of your desired output is invalid

Comment: `{
  "left",
  "right",
  "down",
  "up"
}` is invalid

Comment: also, if  `oppositeDirections` is supposed to be an array, does order matter?

Comment: @NickParsons order does not matter.  I will edit the questions as the name `oppositeDirections` is a copy/paste error.

Comment: 1. `{ vertical: [ 'down', 'up' ], horizontal: [ 'left', 'right' ] }`
2. `{directionValues:  [ 'down', 'up',  'left', 'right' ]}`
3. ` [ 'down', 'up',  'left', 'right' ]`
what is expected output ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to merge the array in `directions.vertical` and `directions.horizontal`?

Might be you meant the result is like this

```
let oppositeDirections = [
  "left",
  "right",
  "down",
  "up"
]
```

If so it should be

```
let directions = {
  "vertical": [
    "down",
    "up",
  ],
  "horizontal": [
    "left",
    "right",
  ]
}

function getDirectionValues() {
  let a = [];
  Object.values(directions).forEach(element => {
    a = [...a, ...element];
  });
  return a;
}

let oppositeDirections = getDirectionValues();
```

Answer (score 1):

I will prefer [**`flat()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) the object values to assign them to the object using [**`Object.assign()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```js
let directions = {
  "vertical": [
    "down",
    "up",
  ],
  "horizontal": [
    "left",
    "right",
  ]
}

function getDirectionValues() {
  let a = {};
  Object.assign(a, Object.values(directions).flat());
  return a;
}
console.log(getDirectionValues());
```

Comment: It's much appreciated that you posted this.  If using output in an array format doesn't work out then I'll use this helpful post to rewrite the code if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

For output : `[ 'down', 'up', 'left', 'right' ]`

```js
let directions = {
  vertical: ["down", "up"],
  horizontal: ["left", "right"]
};
function getDirectionValues1(directions) {
  let a = [];
  for (let key in directions) {
    a.push(...Object.values(directions[key]));
  }
  return a;
}
console.log(getDirectionValues1(directions));
// Output : [ 'down', 'up', 'left', 'right' ]

console.log({ directions: getDirectionValues1(directions) });
// Output:  { directions: [ 'down', 'up', 'left', 'right' ] }

// Enum

function getDirectionValues2(directions) {
  let a = {};
  let counter = 0;
  for (let key in directions) {
    for (let k of directions[key]) {
      a[k] = counter++;
    }
  }
  return a;
}
console.log(getDirectionValues2(directions));
// Output : { down: 0, up: 1, left: 2, right: 3 }

// Revers enum:
function getDirectionValues3(directions) {
  let a = {};
  let counter = 0;
  for (let key in directions) {
    for (let k of directions[key]) {
      a[counter++] = k;
    }
  }
  return a;
}
console.log(getDirectionValues3(directions));
// Output: { '0': 'down', '1': 'up', '2': 'left', '3': 'right' }
```

```css
.as-console-row {color: blue!important}
```